# Visual Studio 2013 unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I have divide one large class with unit tests to few smaller ones in the same folder to organize code, and now test explorer wont show anything.It works perfectly with just one class containing all unit tests.

Comment: Are all the classes public and marked with the correct attributes?

Comment: Thank you  stuartd forgot about such simple thing:)

Answer (score 0):

All classes have to be public for test explorer to find unit test inside them.